# Подключение к устройству, подключенному к роутеру, работающему в режиме репитера через wi-fi

Tags: сеть, роутер, подсети

Мне нужно подключиться к устройству, которое при помощи кабеля подключено к роутеру, в свою очередь данный роутер работает в режиме репитера по wi-fi (т.е. он не подключен напрямую к основному роутеру). То есть надо сделать так, чтобы основной роутер видел подключения репитера, чтобы я смог подключится к устройству.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что я чего-то не понял. Но предположим две ситуации.

Первая: мы имеем непосредственный доступ к основному роутеру и можем с лёгкостью подключить наше устройство по кабелю (будь то ноутбук либо же ПК). Тогда мы это и делаем.

Вторая: роутер основной в неудобном месте, а лишний провод будет мешаться. Так как у наших роутеров различные IP-адреса, мы, соответственно, если наше устройство "дотягивается" сигналом до основного роутера, можем, используя Wi-Fi, подключиться к нему, задав в настройках подключения статичный IP-адрес, которым будет являться IP-адрес основного роутера. Также, если устройство на Windows (про другие ничего не скажу), то, возможно, придётся выставить приоритет нового Wi-Fi-подключения над локальной сетью. Делается это через настройки подключения, снятия галочки с "Автоматического назначения метрик" и установки необходимого приоритета (делается сразу для IPv4 и IPv6)

Comment: Видно я не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос. Устройство, которое мне нужно подключить работает на Linux и там нет доступа к Wi-Fi, только лишь соединение по кабелю. Поскольку основной роутер неудобно использовать для этого устройства я прибегнул к использованию роутера репитера. И вся суть в том, что если я захочу установить подключение из основного роутера, то я смогу пингануть только IP моего роутера репитера, поскольку все, что подключено к этому репитеру является его локальной сетью, к которой нет доступа из вне.

Comment: То есть надо сделать так, чтобы основной роутер видел подключения роутера репитера. Если это невозможно, то скажите об этом.

Comment: Гм, имхо, только через "веб-морду" роутера в режиме "wi-fi репитера" это будет сложно/не реализуемо. Возможно если бы это был микротик какой нибудь, или более/менее полноценный linux - можно было бы "поковыряться", но там скорее речь бы шла о ручной настройке роутера и раздачей вай-фая сконфигурированного аналогично основному ( идентичное название точки доступа, идентичный пароль)...  Может стоит вопрос админам задать, на https://serverfault.com/ или в https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nikita Kalitin, на репитере стоит DD-WRT, а это вроде как более менее полноценный Linux. Благодарю за наводку на дополнительные форумы!